# Midi USB keyboard latency/delay

Tags: usb, sound, midi

Akai Professional MPK Mini via USB, Ubuntu 17.04.

Plugging it in via USB and selecting it in [Sunvox](http://www.warmplace.ru/soft/sunvox/) just works, except there's just this slight but noticeable delay that isn't there when playing on the regular keyboard.

So there's tons of guides, official and not, QAs here and elsewhere, that all seem to say a lot of different things, from new kernels to whatnot.

My question is: given no other requirements on any performance or realtime, what is (likely) the slightest alteration I could do to my system to get MIDI without (noticeable latency), today, in 2017?

I'm fine with installing the low latency kernel etc but only if that's actually still needed to this day. :) Thanks!

Comment: Is that "regular keyboard" also connected with USB, or with plain MIDI cables, or using its internal synthesizer?

Comment: The USB protocol itself does not add more than 2 ms, which should not be noticeable. It's possible that the keyboard itself does its own processing not fast enough.

Comment: @CL. The "regular keyboard" is the one I use to type this with, also by USB yeah. There's a lot of guides out there saying that MIDI is not read in realtime, talking about low latency kernels or adjusting the polling rate and other things. Apparently MIDI is not read as fast as say a keyboard by default. Many of these are really old and there just doesn't seem to be any definite answers, I thought I'd ask if there's a best advice now in 2017.

Comment: How do you "play" with the regular keyboard? What synthesizer are you using with both keyboards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comand:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency
```

works a treat.

In the old days, you had to do it by hand which was a lot more error prone. Yoshimi plug in synth had lagged noticeably from a qwerty keyboard, just as much as from my USB MIDI keyboard input.  Now, it responds practically instantaneously.

Well explained at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudioPreparation